Backtracking data in power bi
I tried backtracking the values of one column based on the minimum values of another column in a new column. Description is given in image. Kindly suggest a formula to get the values as I have to apply it to other places too.
MIN_KBETR=
CALCULATE(
    MIN(ZMOB_TZONE_L1[KBETR]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1,
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[LZONE],
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[INCO1],
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[WGBEZ]
    )
)



Please add your measure code here in the post. People need to copy and test before they help you.

Can you please try this below-
MIN_KBETR=

var min_kbter = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(ZMOB_TZONE_L1[KBETR]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1,
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[LZONE],
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[INCO1],
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[WGBEZ]
    )
)

return
CALCULATE(
    MIN(ZMOB_TZONE_L1[DISTZ]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            ZMOB_TZONE_L1,
            ZMOB_TZONE_L1[LZONE],
            ZMOB_TZONE_L1[INCO1],
            ZMOB_TZONE_L1[WGBEZ]
        ),
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[KBETR] = min_kbter
    )
    
)




Thank you ....it works.....I was doing the same thing, but used selected value with calculate after return. Thanks a lot. Can I ask  a following question , this formula is good for numerical backtracking.....but if there is any text to backtrack....what modifications should be used? Like in above problem....if I have to get route ...regarding min_kbetr......Kindly suggest.

For text, min and max should also work in similar way. But if your text order is not default ASC or DESC, you have to create custom column with appropriate order based on Texts. Then you can apply the min/max on the new custom column.

I think you are wanting:
MIN_DISTZ =
  CALCULATE(
    MIN([DISTZ]),
    FILTER(
      ALLEXCEPT(
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1,
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[LZONE],
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[INCO1],
        ZMOB_TZONE_L1[WGBEZ]
      ),
      [KBETR] = [MIN_KBETR]
    )
  )

